# Can't detect C leaks in xcode 9 instruments

Tags: c, xcode, macos, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm trying to use instruments for the first time. So, I wrote a small C program to detect memory leaks in instruments.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int *temp = NULL;
    temp = (int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i<100; ++i) {
        temp[i] = i;
    }
    printf("%d", *(temp+1));
    printf("Hello   ");
    temp = NULL;
    usleep(10000000);
    printf("%d", *(temp+1));
}
```

[image]

---

When I use `free(temp)`
[image]

---

In the 1st pic, there are no leaks but in the below panel we can see the allocated details.

In the 2nd pic, there are no leaks but in the below panel we can see there are no details.

Why is that? Can anybody explain the output(top and below panels)?

Thank you!

---

**Update:**

You mean like this?

```
int main()
{
    char **temp = NULL;
    temp = (char**)malloc(100*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i<100; ++i) {
        temp[i] = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
        temp[i]=NULL;
        usleep(2000000);
    }
}
```

[image]

P.S I tagged C++ because I think the above code can be written in C++ also. Please remove the tag if I'm wrong.

Comment: In the first example, the leak doesn't count because the program exits straight after setting the pointer to `NULL`. You might get better results by allocating in a loop and setting the pointer to `NULL` in the loop.

Comment: @JeremyP I have updated the answer. Is that what you said to do me?

Comment: More or less. Probably want to write to each allocated piece of RAM though.

Comment: @JeremyP Tried to assign a string in the loop `temp[i] = "Hi, Hello"`. Still there is no leak.

Comment: @unknownymouse maybe the compiler is smart enough to avoid leaks for your simple program.

Comment: Hi @SkrewEverything seeing after long time. Is there any way to create a leak then?

Comment: Just compile your code using terminal. Then change the target to your binary in the instruments.app. It will show you the memory leaks. I guess xcode is optimising your code. So just compile your code without using any optimisation flags

Comment: @SkrewEverything Thank you! It works. You always save my day. Can you post the solution as an answer so that it will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. It creates a memory leak as you expected. The problem(actually its good) is with the Xcode.

Xcode optimises your code to remove all the memory leaks. Thats why instruments not showing any memory leaks.

To see your memory leaks, disable the optimisations in the Xcode.

[image]

Select `None [-O0]` to disable all the optimisations.

---

You use intstruments to profile the final production code. So, don't change the `Release` settings. You may forget to change it back and your program will not be optimised.

Instead edit the scheme of `Profile` from `Release` to `Debug`. Doing this you can always get optimised code for the `Release`.

**1).** Click on executable icon
[image]

**2).** Click on `Edit Scheme`.
[image]

**3).** Change the `Build Configuration` to `Debug`.
[image]

Now, whenever you profile your code, you will get all the errors as your code is not optimised.

To profile your release code, change it back to `Release` in the `Build Configuration`.